# Passing a list of lists to multiprocessing.Pool doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

data_table = None
def init_data_table(my_data_table = [], *args):
    global data_table
    data_table = my_data_table

def process_data(index):
    # create data processor object and run cpu intensive task here
    return str(index) + " " +  data_table[index][0]

def main():
    # call db functions once and get data table from db
    data_table = ...
    pool = Pool(processes = 4, initializer=init_data_table, initargs=(data_table))
    x = pool.map(process_data, range(10))
```

The problem is when I try and pass the `data_table` and access it later on, it does not work . I get this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of passing a complex data structure such as a tuple or list of lists into the `Pool()` function, so it can be accessed by the forked child processes. Essentially it is a shared piece of data that I want to retrieve once only, as it is an expensive call to the db, and I want to make it accessible to the processes.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Some debugging output would help, like `print(index, len(data_table))` to see what the invalid index actually is.

Comment: ok it is return len() = 4. but the data table is 10 by 4, so the initargs is only passing the first list into the function, not a list of lists.

Comment: I bet the root of the problem is in the `data_table = ...` line which you haven't shown us.

Comment: data_table = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8], ... [10,10,10,10]]

Comment: Well, if it's a simple literal nested list then I guess that's not it. Print more stuff out to make sure you're getting what you expect at each stage. For example, what do you get with `print data_table` inside `process_data`?

Comment: data_table = [1,2,3,4] just the first list in the nested list.

Comment: It still feels like you're not showing us the whole problem. Can you create a small, complete example, such that it can be run exactly as written and demonstrates the problem? It's hard to guess what's going on with partial code.

Comment: Actually I think you can run the sample code if you add the data_table example, comment out the return on process_data and it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `multiprocessing.Pool` says this about `initializer`:

> If initializer is not None then each worker process will call
>   initializer(*initargs) when it starts.

So in your case, it's calling `init_data_table(*data_table)`. Because of the `*`, it's going to attempt to unpack your list of lists, taking each sublist and assigning it to a variable in the definition of `init_data_table`. You've defined it as

```
def init_data_table(my_data_table=[], *args):
```

So, when Python tries to unpack this, the first sublist ends up in `my_data_table` and all of the rest end up in a tuple, assigned to `*args`. To avoid this, you need to put your `data_table` into a tuple when you assign it to `initargs`. It actually looks like you tried to do this, but you forgot to include the trailing comma:

```
pool = Pool(processes = 4, initializer=init_data_table, initargs=(data_table,))
```

Then, Python ends up calling `init_data_table(*(data_table,))`, which will unpack your whole `data_table` list in `my_data_table`, leaving `*args` empty, which is what you really want to happen.

Comment: Good spotting! I bet that's where the mystery `*args` came from.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out why that was there at first, either.